# SyndicationItem.Content in .NET

Tags: asp.net, rss, syndication

Is there a reason I can get the `Summary` but not the `Content` of a `SyndicationItem`. I am looking for the entire post. It appears that it depends on how the RSS feed is configured. Is this true?

Can I expect to read the entire content of any RSS feed from the wild? Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I realise this is something of a gravedig, but it's still open and unanswered.

If the content is just text, you could typecast the content to [TextSyndicationContent](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.servicemodel.syndication.textsyndicationcontent.aspx).